# What (if anything) do I need to distribute if using Microsoft.XMLHTTP in VB6?

Tags: windows, vb6

What I've [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) suggests that as long as IE 5.5 or higher is installed then I'm OK.

All users using this feature will have at least IE 6

Comment: I thought MDAC 2.5/2.6 had this.  Not sure about later versions or where you can get a download.

Comment: It is part of MSXML, even though ADO makes some use of it.  There are multiple versions of it that are implemented in multiple versions of MSXML.  Which one your program is dependent upon varies based on how you create instances of the object.  You might be late-binding, in which case the ProgId matters.  You might be early-binding, in which case the typelib you are using makes a difference.

Comment: No matter which way you use it, creating instances from the "universal version" of MSXML (i.e. 3.0) always works without any deployment overhead.  It would be a rare Windows install that doesn't include that, even as far back as Win95 where IE 5.x would have brought it along to the party.